# Drag and Drop Captivate Question: Need 'Submit' button to work similar to 'Next' button

Tags: drag-and-drop, adobe-captivate

I am trying to create Adobe Captivate Quiz and have included Drag and Drop Interactive Questions (along with MCQ questions). How to go to the next slide?

I have changed the text of 'Submit' button to 'Next' button. In 'Drag and Drop' Actions, I have selected the following settings:

[image: Drag and Drop Settings]

The question looks like:

[image: Drag and Drop Question]

The correct answer to this question is 'provide a safe workplace/environment'. When I try to submit a wrong answer or no answer, and click on the 'Next' (Submit) button, the control does not go to the next slide.

I tried to keep these settings:

[image: Trial Settings]

This setting simply gives me 10 attempts to submit right answer. Without going to the next slide.

What settings should I choose and how do I move to the next slide and ensure that the candidate has the freedom to revisit the question n number of times, until they 'Submit' the entire quiz?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag and Drop slides are Content slides and not Adobe Question Slides and hence, changing the number of attempts will not necessarily help.

Number of attempts simply means the number of attempts to reach the correct solution. This means that they will have say 10 attempts to select the correct answer. However, they not be able to proceed to the next slide unless they get the answer right or they are out of attempts.

The best way to implement such questions will be using dropdown Fill In The Blanks or Sequence questions.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you @Tejas. You are right. I really hope Adobe starts including the Drag and Drop slides as Question Slides too!